# Why No Server Side Sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, jboss, distributed-computing

I was perusing the JBoss Remoting documentation and I am trying to understand the reason for bidirectional transport. The documentation states that there could be security implications to allowing the server to establish a socket with a client. I was wondering what some of these cases might be.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They didn't want to give any help for writing trojan horses, worms, viruses, adware, malware, etc.

Most firewalls block connections that are not initiated by a machine on the inside.  If JBoss tried to connect to a client, it would likely be flagged as malicious.